# How to List Unmounted partition of a harddisk and Mount them?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, disk

How to list the disk partition when they are unmounted? 
And how to mount them through terminal?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Listing Unmounted Partitions**

To address the listing of the unmounted partitions part, there are several ways - `lsblk`, `fdisk`, `parted`, `blkid`.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1                             8:1    0 111.8G  0 part /
sdb                                8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                             8:17   0   1.5G  0 part 
├─sdb2                             8:18   0 138.6G  0 part /media/WINDOWS
├─sdb3                             8:19   0   8.1G  0 part 
├─sdb4                             8:20   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5                             8:21   0  68.5G  0 part 
└─sdb6                             8:22   0   5.8G  0 part 
loop0                              7:0    0   100G  0 loop 
└─docker-8:1-1589297-pool (dm-0) 252:0    0   100G  0 dm   
loop1                              7:1    0     2G  0 loop 
└─docker-8:1-1589297-pool (dm-0) 252:0    0   100G  0 dm   
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b5321

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   234440703   117219328   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x96360d50

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     3074047     1536000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2         3074048   293617502   145271727+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       471437312   488396799     8479744   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb4       293617662   471437311    88909825    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       315830272   459382783    71776256   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       459384832   471437311     6026240   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1589297-pool: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1589297-pool doesn't contain a valid partition table
$ sudo parted -l                                                               
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Model: ATA Radeon R7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  120GB  120GB  primary  ext4         boot


Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK2555GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1574MB  1573MB  primary   ntfs            boot, diag
 2      1574MB  150GB   149GB   primary   ntfs
 4      150GB   241GB   91.0GB  extended
 5      162GB   235GB   73.5GB  logical   ext4
 6      235GB   241GB   6171MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 3      241GB   250GB   8683MB  primary   ntfs            hidden


Model: Linux device-mapper (thin-pool) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1589297-pool: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  107GB  107GB  ext4


$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="86df21bf-d95f-435c-9292-273bdbcba056" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System" UUID="F4F688B2F68876A0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="TI105866W0A" UUID="4EBAAE53BAAE36FD" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="HDDRECOVERY" UUID="BC4ED40D4ED3BDF8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="3a6e2270-19a2-49d7-aab3-5efb92d3b3d0" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/loop0: UUID="a3693b88-7899-4628-848d-d9012205cf56" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1589297-pool: UUID="a3693b88-7899-4628-848d-d9012205cf56" TYPE="ext4" 
$
```

One could use a little bit of `AWK` magic to parse output of `lsblk` to list all the unmounted partitions :

```
$ lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '$1~/s.*[[:digit:]]/ && $7==""'              
sdb1 8:17 0 1.5G 0 part 
sdb3 8:19 0 8.1G 0 part 
sdb4 8:20 0 1K 0 part 
sdb5 8:21 0 68.5G 0 part 
sdb6 8:22 0 5.8G 0 part
```

Or alternatively:

```
$ lsblk --noheadings --raw -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '$1~/[[:digit:]]/ && $2 == ""'
sdb1 
sdb2 
sdb3 
sdb4 
sdb5
```

What exactly is happening there is that we're listing all the lines which have first column starting with letter `s` (because that's how drives typically are named) and ending with a number (which represent partitions). In my previous output you could see that I have other filesystems, such as for docker, so in the above command we're getting rid of all the unnecessary stuff.

**Mounting Partitions**

I've found that `mount` can be picky： it needs to know  exact filesystem, it needs to be run as root, etc. `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sXY` is a much better command, can be ran as regular user, and mounts automatically to the `/media/$USER/` folder. For example,

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb5 
Mounted /dev/sdb5 at /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625.
```

Comment: This gives a wrong result for SD readers in a laptop, since `/dev/mmcblk0` also ends with a number and is listed alongside the partition `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I developed for listing unmounted volumes:

```
lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}'
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer with examples on how it is used?

Comment: with modifying it like this: `lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}' | grep -E "(/dev/sd.)[[:digit:]]"` you can get rid of sda, sdb, sdc, and ...

Answer (score 6):

`sudo blkid -o list`

will list all the mounted and unmounted partitions. In addition you can use `mount` and `df` to see all mount points.

`mount -t type device destination_dir`

can be used to mount your device/partition.

Comment: This lists only mounted partitions. Unmounted ones aren't included.

Comment: @Suncat2000 Sorry, but this simple command will also list unmounted partitions.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question, run:

```
sudo parted -l
```

If they are normally mounted, just run:

```
mount -a
```

From the mount man page:
 The command

> mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]
>
> (usually  given  in  a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in
>   fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper
>   options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose line
>   contains the noauto keyword.

If they are not normally mounted you have to provide the options to mount.

Comment: and to be clear the `mount` command needs to be `sudo mount <options>` as well, if run as other than root, or you get: **mount: only root can do that**

Comment: I am too newb to comment directly on @Serg's answer but it's quite exhaustive, at least I can upvote it! Be sure to look at his answer, especially the `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sXY` command which can be run by an average user, very cool.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a script based on the answers that people said here, in this case I list all the unmounted partitions first, and then mount them using udisksctl.

The **final script** will look like this:

```
lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}' | grep -E "(/dev/sd.)[[:digit:]]" | xargs -I{} -n1 udisksctl mount -b {}
```

Here,

`lsblk  --noheadings --raw | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}' | uniq -c | grep 1 | awk '{print "/dev/"$2}'`

will produce *sda sda1 ... sdb sdb1 ... sdc ....* but we don't want *sda* itself, we want *sda1, sda2 ...* so we need to remove *sda, sdb, sdc* themselves,

so we add the

`grep -E "(/dev/sd.)[[:digit:]]"`

section to do that.

Now it produces *sda1,sda2,...,sdb1,sdb2,...*  kinda good now :)

and now we can mount them one by one, by using xargs like this:

`xargs -I{} -n1 udisksctl mount -b {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
blkid -c /dev/nul | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

to get the list of all the mounted partition, and then use `Lsblk` to check which weren't on the mounted list.